# Return value of array.pop();

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to know why
"console.log(a);" is "undefined"

```
const number = ['0', '1', '2'];

const pop = array => {
  array.pop();
}

console.log(number); // [ '0', '1', '2' ]
a = pop(number);
console.log(number); // [ '0', '1' ]
console.log(a); // undefined
b = number.pop();
console.log(number); // [ '0' ]
console.log(b); // 1
```

I expect "undefined" should be "2"

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function. Either `return array.pop()` or remove the `{}` brackets for implicit return like this: `const pop = array => 
  array.pop();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arrow function will implicitly return *only* if the first non-whitespace character after the `=>` is *not* an opening curly brace `{`. Remove the braces to make it a concise function:

```
const pop = array => array.pop();
```

Or use `return` like you would in a normal verbose function:

```
const pop = array => {
  return array.pop();
};
```

Also note that currently `pop` does what `Array.prototype.pop` also does - remove the last element from an array, and return that element. It's simpler not to write your own function, and simply use the inbuilt array method:

```
a = number.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! By the way, I am still confused about 'why the last line is not 'undefined' but '1''.

Comment: That's because you use `number.pop()` and not `pop(number)`, you are not calling your function but `Array.prototype.pop` that does return the value popped.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop function is not returning anything.

Add a return on array.pop() call

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't return anything in your arrow function. 
You could either write

```
const pop = array => {
  return array.pop();
}
```

Or, in a simpler way :

```
const pop = array => array.pop();
```